# UnitTests and iOS : viewDidLoad triggered twice

Tags: ios, unit-testing

I am testing the viewDidLoad event on one of my UIViewController.

```
- (void)testMyView
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    MyViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:MYID];
    [vc viewDidLoad];

    STAssertNotNil(vc, @"MyViewController should not be nil");
}
```

If I remove the line `[vc viewDidLoad];`, the `viewDidLoad` is never triggered.

If I let `[vc viewDidLoad];` in place, the `viewDidLoad` is triggered twice.

I understand that views are lazy loaded, but how can I avoid that behavior?

Is there any best practice regarding View testing?

Comment: use viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad...

Comment: you need to call the `–loadView` method instead of the `–viewDidLoad`... and it won't be invoked twice.

Comment: Well, that was my first try but it does not work. `vc.view.hidden = NO;` did the trick.

Comment: - loadView is for programmatically created view controllers, not ones from nibs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to access the view in order to have it load automatically.

You can use something like this to do it without side effects:

```
vc.view.hidden = NO; // Or YES if it is supposed to be hidden.
```

Oh, and then remove your manual call to `viewDidLoad` as it won't be needed.

Comment: (void)vc.view; will work too, you don't need to access any property on .view. Accessing .view will load the views.

Answer (score 1):

Read my note https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/52

Suppose we have the following view controller

```
class ListController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
  }
}
```

**Get to know viewDidLoad**

We know that viewDidLoad is called when view is created the first time. So in the the Unit Test, if you use viewDidLoad to trigger, you will fall into a trap

```
func testSetup() {
  let controller = ListController()
  controller.viewDidLoad()
}
```

**Why is viewDidLoad called twice?**

It is called once in your test
And in your viewDidLoad method, you access view, which is created the first time, hence it will trigger viewDidLoad again

**The correct way**

The best practice is not to trigger events yourself, but do something to make event happen. In Unit Test, we just access view to trigger viewDidLoad

```
func testSetup() {
  let controller = ListController()
  let _ = controller.view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do lazy loading using [vc view];

Answer (score 0):

Call [`layoutIfNeeded()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded?language=objc) on the view controller's view, namely:

```
[vc.view layoutIfNeeded]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the following call to execute the viewDidLoad only once:

```
_ = vc.view
```